# Retrieving most recent record per id. How to, in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables. One table stores basic information on inventory items like id and description. The other table stores the status of the inventory items at the end of each day; so there are many rows in this table with the same inventoryItemID but different dates. Below is basically what my tables look like.

```
TABLE: listItems
|itemRecordNumber|itemName|minStock|reorderQty|note|
|      510       |  bag   |   10   |    20    |    |
|      511       |  ball  |   20   |    40    |    |
|      512       |  shoe  |   09   |    10    | xx |
```

,

```
TABLE: inventoryTrans
|itemRecordNumber|recordType|quantity| trans_date |
|      510       |    50    |   30   | 09/12/2013 |
|      510       |    40    |   33   | 09/12/2013 |
|      510       |    50    |   35   | 08/12/2013 |
|      510       |    40    |   35   | 08/12/2013 |
|      511       |    50    |   10   | 08/12/2013 |
|      511       |    40    |   15   | 09/12/2013 |
|      512       |    50    |   33   | 07/12/2013 |
|      512       |    40    |   34   | 09/12/2013 |
```

Now, what i want is, the most recent record from the table inventoryTrans for each itemRecordNumber and only the records of type 50(a sale), but wait theres more, if the note in the table listItems on an item is 'xx' i am not interested in that result. What i really need from this table is the quantity. Notice this table does not have the items name / minStock / reorderQty , which is why i need the first table listItems, to get that info.

So in a single query i would like to get,

```
|itemRecordNumber|itemName| trans_date |quantity|minStock|reorderQty|
|      510       |  bag   | 09/12/2013 |   30   |   10   |    20    |
|      511       |  ball  | 08/12/2013 |   10   |   20   |    40    |
```

So what i want is this information. Notice it is the most recent of the recordType '50' for each ID, yet item 512 was excluded due to the note on the item being 'xx' in listItems.note ;

Now before you criticize the construct of the tables, it is not something I can change. This is how the tables for Peachtree accounting(the software my company at hand is using) is layed out, so this is what I have to work with. The goal is to generate custom information on inventory for better management.

Now how can I construct a SQL query for this. i have seen people use LEFT JOIN in some other similar examples but i cant get it to work.

Comment: Just for your person reference, check [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) out

Answer (score 1):

Here we go

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d30823/1 this is the example with your data

```
SELECT a.itemRecordNumber,
       a.itemName,
       max(b.trans_date) AS trans_date,
       b.quantity,
       a.minStock,
       a.reorderQty
FROM listItems a,
     inventoryTrans b
WHERE a.itemRecordNumber = b.itemRecordNumber
  AND a.note<>'xx'
  AND b.recordtype=50
GROUP BY a.itemRecordNumber
```

Edit:
In case of MS Access (which I am unable to test), this should work, can you try (I did try in MS SQL which is the closest I can test in SQLFiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d30823/2

```
SELECT a.itemRecordNumber,
       a.itemName,
       max(b.trans_date) AS trans_date,
       b.quantity,
       a.minStock,
       a.reorderQty
FROM listItems a,
     inventoryTrans b
WHERE a.itemRecordNumber = b.itemRecordNumber
  AND a.note<>'xx'
  AND b.recordtype=50
  AND b.trans_date =
    (SELECT max(trans_date)
     FROM inventoryTrans c
     WHERE c.itemRecordNumber = b.itemRecordNumber
       AND c.recordtype=50)
GROUP BY a.itemRecordNumber,
         a.itemName,
         b.quantity,
         a.minStock,
         a.reorderQty
```

Let me know if it does not work for you for any reason, I got the same results as your question

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, I edited my question. I think that Microsoft Access is giving trouble because i cant seem to get this sql statement to work. Im always getting the error "" You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'itemName' as part of an aggregate function. ""  and if i delete the SELECT for itemName, the error shifts to 'quantity', if i remove that, then 'minStock' and finally 'reorderQty'. So all that i get to show is itemRecordNumber and trans_date. i can only assume the rest is working but i cant say cause i cant view the quantity

Comment: Yes Mysql can tolerate more fields in the select than in the group by, none of the other databases would tolerate that (as far as I know).  In other cases you have to approach it differently, are you using ms access or mysql? I am sorry if I misunderstood, but if you want access I can look up since I havent been using that in a long time

Comment: I have added a MS SQL solution that may work for Access please check and let me know if it does work

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply (even though im late)! The second set of code you edited in seems to be error free, but my mc access seems to have trouble with a sub-query cause i keep getting a timeout error. These tables have a hell of a lot of items in them. The itemList has over 2500 inventory items, and the inventoryTrans table will have 25x that of the itemList table. is there a way to query the second table first to get all the most recent type 50s for each itemRecondNumber, and have that data in a temporary table, and then use that table with the item list to get the final result ?

Comment: if the data is not confidential can you send me the file

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not the most efficient way, it should work.

```
SELECT l.*, i.trans_date, i.quantity
FROM listItems as l
    JOIN (SELECT i.itemRecordNumber, MAX(trans_date) as date
          FROM inventoryTrans as i GROUP BY i.itemRecordNumber
     ) as x ON x.itemRecordNumber = l.itemRecordNumber
    JOIN inventoryTrans as i ON l.itemRecordNumber = i.itemRecordNumber
        AND i.trans_date = x.date
WHERE i.recordType = 50
```

Though this will give a row for `itemRecordNumber = 512` too, if you do not need it you can add a `WHERE` and filter according to your need.